# Release button while other button execute methods WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following problem:
I have to Buttons. 
After a click on the first button the program start a while loop. 
I like to leave this while loop after click on the second button.

How I can do this?

Have anyone an idea?

Thank [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WJsJ.png)

Comment: You can't. The while loop will block the main ui thread, so no other input can be caught. You have to move the loop in another thread (ex. Timer, Task, ecc are all classes that help you do that). The buttons then just start the thread and stop it (even as simple as changing the flag in the 'while(flag)' loop)

Comment: Use a DispatcherTimer. It has an Interval property to control the frequency, a Tick event where you attach a handler method, and Start and Stop methods.

Comment: @Clemens can you give me more information about that?

Comment: Still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple threads to accomplish this. I suggest reading up on the subject and looking at some examples.

There are a number of different classes/systems that can do this, because newer, better ones were developed over time. `BackgroundWorker` is an example of an old system that I wouldn't recommend for new development. I believe the current best practices (at the time of writing) are to use the `Dispatcher` (in WPF) as well as `async`/`await`.

Here is some documentation:

[MSDN - Threading Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model)
[Building Responsive UI using Async Await in C#](https://www.mithunvp.com/building-responsive-ui-using-async-await-csharp/)